# Remove ActionForm property from struts 1 session

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, struts

I would know how remove or update value from a property of FormBean(action form) in struts 1.

I have some properties which are (name, code, cellphone). I want remove after request the value from name because I need perform comparison again in that field.

The variables of my FormBean are fill through from `<html:hidden>` that I send to my form using a javascript function but I when performed the second request the values are all there again.

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

after all the work is done in your StrutsAction. Right before the forwardStatement you could do this:

```
formBean.setName("");
request.getSession().setAttribute("formBean", formBean);
```